# space lost when converting inline cell to tex

Tags: latex

> Sample Cell 1
>   words with spaces in one inline cell

```
Cell[TextData[Cell[BoxData[\(TraditionalForm\`\(Y\ =\ \(\({\(x\ \[Element]\ \([\(a,\ b\)]\)\)\ :\ \(there\ is\ a\ finite\ subcover\ in\ \(\[Sum]\ \(of\ the\ \(interval\ [\(a,\ x\)]\)\)\)\)}\) .\ \)\)\)], "InlineFormula", FormatType -> "TraditionalForm"]], "Text"]
```

---

When saving it as Tex, or `Copy As Latex`, the spaces between words will lost,

What's the right and good method to deal with such thing? The worst is each time this happen, I modify it in Tex Editor.

---

As Silva's answer suggested, creating text cell for inline words block. What occurred in my mind is to develop some palletes like this post(my prevous quesion) to do the similar thing.
[How to make AutoAction take effect only one time?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26044/how-to-make-autoaction-take-effect-only-one-time)

---

As you see in the picture, I'm handling the `InlineFormula` with blue color. In the biggest blue block, there are two words block`there is a finite subcover in` and `of the interval`. Consider one possible situation, there are five or more words block in the inline cell with depth 2.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that is because you put your text all in an `"InlineFormula"` Cell, which is an equivalent to the LaTeX inline formula environment (*i.e.* `$...$`), so they are understand as many variables multiply together. And as you know, spaces between multipliers are omitted by default.

The following code works on my computer:

```
Cell[TextData[
   Cell[BoxData[FormBox[RowBox[{"Y", "=", RowBox[{"{", RowBox[{

            RowBox[{"x", "\[Element]", 
              RowBox[{"[", RowBox[{"a", ",", "b"}], "]"}]}],

            Cell[": there is a finite subcover in ", "Text"],

            "\[CapitalSigma]",

            Cell[" of the interval ", "Text"],

            RowBox[{"[", RowBox[{"a", ",", "x"}], "]"}]
            }], "}"}]}], TraditionalForm]]]], "Text"] // CellPrint
```

[image]

Then copy the printed cell into a new notebook and save it as *TeX*:

[image]

Render it with mathjax engine on this site:

$Y=\{x\in [a,b]\text{: there is a finite subcover in }\Sigma \text{ of the interval }[a,x]\}$

Comment: hi, Suppose my default new inline cell style is `InlineFormula`, then I selected the content(Y={x...[a,x]}) in one Text-Style cell and type `ctrl+(` to create one inline cell, but if I choose the words `there is a finite subcover in` and create another inline cell, it's style is also `InlineFormula` unless I changed style to `Text`, and futher, if there are 5 parts of words block, I should select 5 times and change inline cell style, seems too boring.

Comment: @HyperGroups yes it's annoying.. There used to be a typesetting system made by *Wolfram Research* called *Publicon*, maybe you would like to try it.

Comment: Wolfram has discontinued the sale of Publicon. Publicon's advanced technical publishing capabilities are merging into functionality in Mathematica and other Wolfram technologies.http://www.wolfram.com/products/publicon/
Seems that's not a long-run choice.

Comment: I've updated the post and added one prevous link about a pallete to create and flatten inline cells.
The inconvenient is I should move my mouse/cursor to the pallete, If there would be some similar function like Format-Brush in Microsoft-Word, that would be better.

Comment: @HyperGroups Hmm.. OT: I think format-frush in *MS-Word* is a real disaster for structured typesetting.. One should define the *styles* first and use them as *describers* in the text body. I see you're from China, so I presume you read Chinese, thus I suggest a great book on typesetting in *Word*: 《Word排版艺术》. Hope it helps.

Comment: well,,,actually I've downloaded that book several years ago, but without read it.
Just now, I think that I can scan the inline cell with Depth-2 and changed them into Text. I think Wolfram should develop the control and formatting of inline cells, 9.0's New function `Cells` does not scan inline cells by default unless find some specific content.

Comment: @HyperGroups Scanning the whole cell is a right way to go, I think. Maybe you would like to develop the idea to a concrete code and provide an good answer to this question :)